# What's the meaning of this syntax: Organization<(Currency, Coupon?) -> Sustenance>()

Tags: kotlin, generics, syntax

I stumbled upon this seemingly obscure syntax in [an article about type aliases](https://typealias.com/guides/all-about-type-aliases/).

In Intellij IDEA this code compiles fine:

```kotlin
  class Currency
  class Coupon
  open class Organization<SustenanceT>
  class Sustenance
  class Restaurant : Organization<(Currency, Coupon?) -> Sustenance>()
```

Not knowing how the syntax is named, I couldn't find any information on Google since keywords like "<(" seem to be ignored. In the Kotlin documentation I didn't find this syntax on pages about generics. The only relevant search result there was [this short section about C function pointers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mapping-function-pointers-from-c.html#c-function-pointers-in-kotlin) but it doesn't explain much;

What's the meaning of this syntax, and for what use cases can I apply it in my projects?

Comment: Do you understand e.g. what `(Int) -> String` or `Organisation<String>` means?

Comment: Ah, got it I guess... This makes the class accept a function that accept Currency and Coupon and returns Sustenance as a type parameter?

Comment: Just saw your edit of "as a type parameter". Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks, that's some effective teaching :) Use case is obvious. If you post an answer I'll accept it right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are parsing the syntax incorrectly. `<(` is not a token. Let me add some whitespace:

```
Organization<
    (Currency, Coupon?) -> Sustenance
>
```

`(Currency, Coupon?) -> Sustenance` is a *type* that represents a function which accepts a `Currency` and `Coupon?` as parameters, and returns a `Sustenance`.

This type is then used as the type parameter of `Organisation`, just like the `String` in `List<String>`. What this means exactly will depend on what `Organisation`'s type parameter represents. From the article, it seems to mean "the thing that the organisation does", so all in all, the entire type represents

> an organisation that converts currency and coupon to sustenance